# Accessing a Windows share (restricted access) on Windows using PHP

Tags: php, iis, networking, share

I already read similar articles but in the end I find myself in a bit different situation...
I want to use a network share which is hosted somewhere else. The access is restricted but I got an account with permission to use it.

I did not find any solutions for Windows Server+IIS. I understand that sambaclients do not work on windows and other approaches like using windows system utils

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
+
net use z: \\[IP ADDRESS HERE]\[FOLDER NAME HERE] /persistent:yes
```

It did not work, either. What am I supposed to do? I am quite confuse that there is no obvious/simple solution for a such a standard problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question by using code tags to display your code.

Answer (score 0):

The last - most promising - approach was to use net use over system():

```
$this->letter = "P";
$this->location = "\\\\IP-adress\\share";
$this->user = "a";
$this->pass = "b"; 

system("net use " . $this->letter .": ". $this->location." ".$this->pass." /user:".$this->user." /persistent:yes 2>&1");

if(is_dir($this->letter)){..}else{}
```

... I always reach the else{}. I verified the command syntax by trying it manually using cmd. This works. But I noticed that I won't see the share "P:\" in explorer if map the share in the script... (Flag for persistency only set true because of visibilty in explorer). But on the other side system() reports that the device is already in use (or something) if I try again.. So I don't really know wheter the system command did work or not.. Anyway, further usage of the share does not work..